# You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined

Tags: neo4j, nosql, spring-data, spring-cloud, spring-data-rest

Yesterday this solution was working fine. Today I woke up to rerun the tests & it failed stating in the stacktrace that ***You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:533)***

As clearly shown I did not define any query methods.  :-(

I'm stuck, I shall try reverting to the previous version & see where we go from there. Please help anyone can.

My Setup is as follows -->

build.gradle ->>

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.0.M1'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2"

    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'


allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
}

group 'io.db'
version '1.0'
sourceCompatibility = 8 //10

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

ext {
    springBootAdminVersion = '2.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactoryContextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev-local'
            username = "${artifactoryUser}"
            password = "${artifactoryPass}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev'
            username = "${artifactoryUser}"
            password = "${artifactoryPass}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "account"
        property "sonar.projectName", "Account-Service"
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.binaries", "build/classes"
        property "sonar.tests", "src/test/java"
        property "sonar.dynamicAnalysis", "reuseReports"
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-reports"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/test-reports/jacoco.exec"
        property 'sonar.coverage.exclusions', "io.db.accountservice.config.persistence.LiveConfig*"
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:5.0.9.RELEASE')
    compile('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver:3.1.1-RC1')
    compile('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-http-driver:3.1.1-RC1')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:Finchley.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client')
//    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons-core:1.4.1.RELEASE')
//    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-dependencies', version: 'Finchley.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'


    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver:3.1.1-RC1')
    testCompile('org.neo4j.test:neo4j-harness:3.4.5')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-dependencies:${springBootAdminVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

TestClass ->>

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class UserRepoTest {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserRepoTest.class); //ToDo: Run the tests with the Live profile to ensure stability.
    private final User user1 = new User();
    private final User user2 = new User();
    private UserRepo UserRepo;
    private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        LOGGER.info("Testing Neo4j DB tests kicking off...");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        LOGGER.info("Testing Neo4j DB tests tearing down...");
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        UserRepo.deleteAll();
        user1.setName("Sean");
        user1.setUsername("sean@test.io");
        user1.setEnabled(true);
        user1.setPassword("new-password");

        user2.setName("Steven");
        user2.setUsername("steven@test.io");
        user2.setEnabled(false);
        user2.setPassword("old-password");
        userList.add(user1);
        userList.add(user2);
    }

    @After
    public void aftermath() {
        UserRepo.deleteAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepo(UserRepo UserRepo) {
        this.UserRepo = UserRepo;
    }

    @Test
    public void aSaveUserAndFindUser() {

        final User SavedUser = UserRepo.save(user1);
        final Optional<User> optionalSavedUser = Optional.of(SavedUser);

        final Optional<User> foundUser = Optional.ofNullable(UserRepo.findByUsername("sean@test.io"));

        assertTrue(optionalSavedUser.isPresent());
        LOGGER.debug("Saved UserID: " + optionalSavedUser.get().getId());
        assertNotNull("User object doesn't have an id.", optionalSavedUser.get().getId());
        assertTrue(foundUser.isPresent());
        assertTrue(user1.getUsername().equals(foundUser.get().getUsername()));
        assertTrue(user1.getName().equals(foundUser.get().getName()));
        assertTrue(user1.getPassword().equals(foundUser.get().getPassword()));
        assertTrue(foundUser.get().getEnabled());
    }
}
```

Application executor class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class AccountRepoApp {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountRepoApp.class);
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    public AccountRepoApp(UserRepo userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    /**
     * Spring Application launcher
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccountRepoApp.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * We need some initialised data to test out the live instance of the App.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        userRepo.deleteAll(); //delete any pre-existing data.
        User user1 = new User(), user2 = new User();
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

        user1.setName("Sean");
        user1.setUsername("sean@test.io");
        user1.setEnabled(true);
        user1.setPassword("new-password");
        user1.setCreated(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        user1.setLastUpdated(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

        user2.setName("Steven");
        user2.setUsername("steven@test.io");
        user2.setEnabled(false);
        user2.setPassword("old-password");
        user2.setCreated(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        user2.setLastUpdated(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

        userList.add(user1);
        userList.add(user2);

        LOGGER.info("User-1: " + user1.toString());
        LOGGER.info("User-2: " + user2.toString());

        userRepo.saveAll(userList);
    }
}
```

DevConfig.java class:

```
@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "io.db.accountservice.repo")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "io.db.accountservice.domain")
@EnableNeo4jAuditing(setDates = true, modifyOnCreate = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DevConfig {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    // with domain entity base package(s)
    return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "io.db.accountservice.domain");
}

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
    //Note: No Config Required when in test/dev-mode.
        return new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration
                .Builder()
                .build();
}

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Boolean enabled;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastUpdated;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date created;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", enabled=" + enabled +
                ", lastUpdated=" + lastUpdated +
                ", created=" + created +
                '}';
    }

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

UserRepo.java interface:

```
@Repository
@RestResource(path = "users", rel = "user")
public interface UserRepo extends Neo4jRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

    User findByName(String name);
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountRepoApp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:736)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:201)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:825)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:865)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
        ... 26 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1743)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1132)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:824)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:727)
        ... 44 more
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:533)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:318)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:195)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:78)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:296)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(Neo4jRepositoryFactoryBean.java:66)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1739)
        ... 55 more

        2018-08-22 01:14:58.550  INFO 20978 --- [           main] io.db.accountservice.repo.UserRepoTest   : Testing Neo4j DB tests tearing down...
        2018-08-22 01:14:58.551  WARN 20978 --- [       Thread-4] o.n.o.d.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver   : Deleting temporary file store: file:/tmp/neo4j.db6708155468020884090/

        Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by rolling back to the previous versions of the SpringBootVersion & the SpringCloudVersion inside the build.gradle script:

```
ext {
    springBootAdminVersion = '2.0.4'
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.SR1'
}
```