# "You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined" after Spring boot version update

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, couchbase

When trying to upgrade our `Spring Boot` app from verions `2.0.4.RELEASE` to version `2.1.6.RELEASE` we get the following error during the application startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have defined query method in the repository but you don't have any query lookup strategy defined. The infrastructure apparently does not support query methods!
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:545)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211)
at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.CouchbaseRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CouchbaseRepositoryFactoryBean.java:105)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
```

We have a Couchbase DB, and here is the Repository class:

```
public interface CatRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Cat, String>{
  Cat findByOwnerNameAndCityName(String ownerName, String cityName);
  List<Cat> findAllByOwnerNameOrderByCityName(String ownerName);
  List<Cat> findAllByLoveToEatNotLike(String food);
}
```

We found [this very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957980/you-have-defined-query-method-in-the-repository-but-you-dont-have-any-query-loo) question that ended up with a version downgrade.

We also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656860/you-have-defined-query-method-in-the-repository-but-you-dont-have-any-query-loo) that involves `Flux` that we don't have in our project.

Comment: Please add your pom or gradle build file so that we can check your dependencies.

Comment: Try upgrading your spring-data dependency, hopefully it should resolve the issue